# FPDF AutoPagination with Rect()

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I am trying to create id cards from records in my database. where the photo of a person would be on the left side and items of information like would be printed by the side and beneath as in the screenshot below. [Screenshot of pdf output showing pagination issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/og22s.png)

Using fpdf cells I am able to create pdfs with pagination. But for the said purpose I thought using the Rect() would be the best for the task, however, It does not respond to autopage break. I also realize there is a logical error in my code but this is the only way I could get the 3 column output. I shall be glad to receive assistance correcting the errors in the code below. Thank you!

```
class PDF extends FPDF {
    function Header(){
        $this->SetFont('Arial', '', 10);
        $this->Cell(18, 10, '', 0);
        $this->SetFont('Arial', '', 9);
        $this->Cell(35, 10, 'Date: '.date('d-m-Y').'', 0);
        $this->Ln(12);
        $this->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 11);
        $this->Cell(70, 8, '', 0);
        $this->Cell(100, 8, 'LIST', 0);
        $this->Ln(13);
    }

    function Footer(){
        $this->SetY(-15);
        $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
        $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');
    }
}

$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->AddPage();


$staff = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM staff");
$item = 0;
$width = 60;
$height = 40;
$x = 15;
$y = 35;
$margin = 2;
while($a_staff = mysql_fetch_array($staff)){
    $item = $item+1;
    for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++){
        $pdf->Rect($x, $y, $width, $height, 'D');
        $pdf->Image('images.gif' , $x+$margin ,$y+$margin, 25 , 25);
        $x = ($x + $width + $margin);
    }
    $y = $y + $height + $margin;
    $x = 15;
}

$pdf->Output( "report.pdf", "I" );
?>
```

Comment: You should avoid learning or writing new code using PHP's `mysql_*` functions. They have been removed in the latest version and your code won't work in the future. Please read [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) for information on why and what to replace them with.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the starting Y coordinate and the height of the content you are adding, you can do the pagination manually.

After `$y = $y + $height + $margin;`, add:

```
// replace 20 with whatever margin you need at the bottom of the page
if ($y + $height > $pdf->h - 20) {
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $y = 35;
}
```